# Xamarin iOS Debugging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to debug a Xamarin application on my iPhone which is connected to my Windows machine but Visual Studio does not display my iPhone in the options list. It displays an option named "Device" and when I click debug choosing it, "please select a valid device" warning appears.

From the image shown on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_in_xamarin_ios/, it seems like Xamarin supports debugging on an iPhone connected to the Windows machine (it shows "Amy's iPhone 6" on the list) but I can't have VS list my device. What can be the problem?

Comment: Follow this guide it will help you https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/

Comment: @ParthPatel This guide is about setting up the provisioning profile. It does not seem to contain information about debugging on a PC connected device.

Comment: The physical iPhone needs to be attached to the Mac. There are USB-over Ethernet extenders if your Mac is not physically in the same room, I been using them for on the cylinder Mac Pros for quite a while... There are also USB software-based redirection applications for macOS, but they are expensive and I have never had great reliability with them when using them for iPhone redirection.

Comment: USB remoting for iOS devices to connect to Windows is announced but not released. You still have to attach them to Mac right now.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you can not compile or deploy apps for iOS on Windows. Your Windows machine where you develop the Xamarin app on needs to be connected to a MacOS device. When you hit `Debug` the iOS compiler on MacOS will compile the code and create the app package. Your iPhone needs to be connected there as well. See here for more info on that.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

Apple does not allow to build apps for their platforms on other operating systems. So even if this would technically be possible, you will always need a MacOS for this.